# Problems with Keyboard Events in library “globalmousekeyhook”

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, keyboard-hook, mousekeyhook

When using library "globalmousekeyhook", two problems arose:

**Problem #1: Global events do not work when called from a separate class**

```
- If place the code to activate Global Events in a separate class (in a method) and then call it from the main form (FormName_Load) - then Global Events stops working (nothing happens).

- If use the code to activate Global Events in the main form (FormName_Load), without wrappers - everything works.
```

**Problem #2: App Events working strangely**

Having written the code for changing the background, separately, in both forms:

```
// Install listener App [Combinations]
Hook.AppEvents().OnCombination(new Dictionary<Combination, Action> {
    { Combination.FromString("Control + S"), () => { this.BackColor= Color.Black; }
}});
```

After startup  forms (Form1.Hide(); Form2.Show();), when you activate the key combination (Ctrl + S) - the color changed in both forms (need the color to change only in the active form).

Comment: `If (ActiveForm == this) { ... }`

Comment: Thank you! This code helped me with App Events, it's a pity  have to a check every time.